# Convert time duration like in JIRA time log #h #m #s format into 00:00:00

Tags: php

I want to convert my time duration from `1h 20m 53s` into `01:20:53` format. My time duration may only have `20m 53s` or `25m` or `1h` or `23s`. I need to convert that into time format of `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex of `^(?:(?<hours>\d+)h\s*)?(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m\s*)?(?:(?<seconds>\d+)s\s*)?$` and `sprintf` to make sure that zeroes are prepended:

```
<?php

function translateTime($timeString) {
    if (preg_match('/^(?:(?<hours>\d+)h\s*)?(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m\s*)?(?:(?<seconds>\d+)s\s*)?$/', $timeString, $matches)) {
        return sprintf(
            '%02s:%02s:%02s',
            (!empty($matches['hours'])   ? $matches['hours']   : '00'),
            (!empty($matches['minutes']) ? $matches['minutes'] : '00'),
            (!empty($matches['seconds']) ? $matches['seconds'] : '00')
        );
    }

    return '00:00:00';
}

var_dump( translateTime('1h 20m 53s') ); //string(8) "01:20:53"
var_dump( translateTime('20m 53s') );    //string(8) "00:20:53"
var_dump( translateTime('53s') );        //string(8) "00:00:53"
var_dump( translateTime('1h 30s') );     //string(8) "01:00:30"
var_dump( translateTime('2h 3m') );      //string(8) "02:03:00"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/133766)

While looking scary the regex is just a bunch of named capture groups:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`\s` is a white space character (space, tab, `\r`, `\n`, `\f`)
`\d` is a digit (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`)

Comment: This is just a style preference, but you can simplify the formatting to `return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $matches['hours'],  $matches['minutes'], $matches['seconds']);`.

Comment: @Vatev What if those matches aren't set seeing as they're optional? `return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', (!empty($matches['hours']) ? $matches['hours'] : '00), (!empty($matches['minutes']) ? $matches['minutes'] : '00), (!empty($matches['seconds']) ? $matches['seconds'] : '00));` would work, but is *very* long. **Edit**: In multiple lines it sure does look better than the previous solution - you're very right.

Comment: I guess I'm too used to ignoring php notices. It doesn't get much better if you want to avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

first make the string compatible with php DateTime object

```
$time = preg_split( "/(h|m|s)/i", " 1H 20m 53s " , null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$h = 0;
$m = 0;
$s = 0;

$count = count($time);

if ($count == 7)
{
    ${strtolower($time[1])} = $time[0];
    ${strtolower($time[3])} = $time[2];
    ${strtolower($time[5])} = $time[4];
}
else if ($count == 5)
{
    ${strtolower($time[1])} = $time[0];
    ${strtolower($time[3])} = $time[2];
}
else if ($count == 3)
{
    ${strtolower($time[1])} = $time[0];
}

$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTime($h, $m, $s);
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

you can now post it in any format php DateTime supports

Comment: There might be the case that user might not enter like **1h20m53s**. I will have problem using explode() in that case. Any other solution?

Comment: Yeah I updated my solution. And now you have a DateTime Object so it is a lot more flexible because you can also very easily calculate difference between different times